# Image processing tools for WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm looking for any useful library or tool for processing image in Windows Phone. The tool / library should be capable of applying effects/filters like sepia, negative and some more difficult like polaroid, amber etc.

Comment: What have you tried, and what is not working for you?  You have not provided enough detail for anybody to help you effectively here.

Comment: @ZombieSheep I've just started. I do not want to reinvent the wheel, I just want to know what should I use for beginning. Simple googling has been unsuccessful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://picfx.codeplex.com/ you can download the source code and see how the effects are processed.

Comment: PixFx is very handy.. rolling out effects is challening however :)

Answer (score 2):

in addition to pixfx you might want to look at http://imagetools.codeplex.com which has additional set of functionality

adding / finding / coding effects is not an easy task.. both the libs will help you get started.

if you just want an app, you can use Pictures Lab. my own app Cool Camera provides in app picture editor (for pictures taken with the app only)